# Postgres user does not connect to database. Even with environment variables set correctly

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, digital-ocean

Heyy, I have been struggling with this for a few days now. Hope you guys can help me out.

**EDIT: After trying to print the password of the Postgres user that I have set in my settings and imported as an environment variable in my gunicorn.service file it doesn't return any value. Locally this does work. So there is an issue with importing the environment variable from the gunicorn.service file. How can I solve this?**

I have hosted a website on Digital Ocean using ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, virtualenv, Postgres and Django and while the site is visible and working, logging into the admin page gives me this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://www.***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"
Exception Location: /***/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 130
Python Executable:  ***
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

**Note: for privacy reasons I have replaced the user for postgres with "usr" ,the websites address with "***" and the database name with "db".**

The connection is not happening between my Postgres user and Postgres database.

When I run:`sudo -u postgres psql -U usr db` I get the same error.

---

I use environment variables for the passwords as you can see below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["DB_PASS"],
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

My environment variables are in the .bashrc file:

```
export DB_PASS="*******"

export SECRET_KEY="******************************"
```

when I run the python shell and print the DB_PASSWORD that I import from the OS library, the password is correct.

My gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=*****
Environment=SECRET_KEY="**********************************"
Environment=DB_PASS="***********"
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/***/vp/vp/
ExecStart=/home/***/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/***/v$


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

EDIT:

When I get in psql and use `\l+` to list all databases I get the following table:

```
                                                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   |  Size   | Tablespace |                Description                 
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                       | 6992 kB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 6857 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            | 
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +| 6857 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres |         |            | 
 db      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +| 7600 kB | pg_default | 
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+|         |            | 
           |          |          |             |             | vpusr=CTc/postgres    |         |            |
```

The list of users `\du`:

```
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 vp        |                                                            | {}
 usr     |                                                            | {}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question here is whether gunicorn is run with the environment variables set. With .bashrc you're setting the environment variables for the shell of the user, but when the system launches gunicorn, it's not using the shell. Depending on which tool you use to launch gunicorn, make sure to set the correct user and environment variables.

Comment: I've added the environment variables in the gunicorn.service file. Still getting the exact same error. even after restarting everything and reloading everything with systemctl. I will add my gunicorn.service file above now

Comment: Check your quotes (`"`) against my answer below. That's what works for me.

Comment: good catch! but sadly that did not fix the error

Comment: wait, one step back: you're also getting an error when you try to connect to the db manually using psql?

Comment: Yes I do! that means that the variables are actually ok

Comment: Your usr doesn't have any privileges, it needs the 'Create DB' role. But to be honest, I would be surprised if that causes the error you see (password authentication failure).

Comment: You're settings.py is looking for `DB_PASSWORD` but your gunicorn.services file is setting `DB_PASS`

Comment: @c17r I've changed that for privacy, but thank you!

Comment: I understand you've hidden the actual password but look at the code one has `os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"]` while the other says `Environment=DB_PASS=`.  The environmental variable **names** are different.

Comment: @c17r . I changed the name of the environment variable. not the actual password. I've changed my code in the question so that you can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're setting the environment variables for the gunicorn process. Setting them in .bashrc only works if you launch gunicorn from the command line yourself. There's 2 ways:

- If you use systemd: Inside your .service file, add

  ```
  [Service]
  ...
  EnvironmentFile=/pathto/somefilewith_secrets
  ```

  or add the environment variables directly:

  ```
  [Service]
  ...
  Environment="DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypassword"
  ```
- Or add the `-e` option to the line for launching the gunicorn service:

  ```
  /path-to-virtualenv/gunicorn 
      --bind unix:/path_to_myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application 
      -e DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypassword -e my_var2=value2
  ```

Comment: i have changed the quotations, same error. I reloaded everything again

Comment: I'm at loss :-) Did you try the second option? This one worked for me as well, but I didn't like it as I keep my env variables in a separate conf file. Oh, and make sure you also `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing your .service files (before `systemctl reload gunicorn`)

Comment: Yep, I tried it. And that didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: by the way, adding a line in one of your django views (that doesn't try to access the db) to print the settings variables to console will help you make sure you have these settings correct.

Comment: how do I import them from gunicorn? the same os.environ?

Comment: no, I mean `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.DATABASES['default']['password']`.

Comment: hey @dirkgroten, locally it works and shows me the password. But on my production server, it doesn't. it comes out blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152152/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-tony-kyriakidis).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your user exists in postgres and has access to the db?

Comment: I just checked the users. the user does exist. I also checked who the owner is of the database. it says postgres even though I granted all privilages to the usr. I will add them now in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i have in my DATABASES section in settings.py

```
> DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'usr',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
```

I prefer using `os.environ.get` to `os.environ`.

`os.environ` raises an exception if the key is not found and `os.environ.get` returns None

Comment: Nope that's not it. no change. I think the issue is with my user in postgres and it's access to the database

Answer (score 0):

the question is pretty old and not sure if you made it to the other end of this tunnel. I faced a somewhat similar issue while deploying my app to a Linode ubuntu machine and here's what worked for me:

In my setting.py file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'xxx',
    'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
    'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PWD'],
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

I defined my environment variables in the /etc/environment file with the straightforward convention

```
DB_USER='my_user'
DB_PWD='my_pwd'
```

Restarted the server, and there it was!